# Ext has many association store does not load

Tags: extjs

I have two models defined, ScoreCard and CaregoryWeight. A ScoreCard has many CategoryWeights.

When I create a grid and pass the association store to it (scoreCard.categoryWeights()), it displays nothing even though items are returned from the RESTful service.

What is wrong? please help.

Below is my code:

```
Ext.define(ModelNames.CategoryWeight, {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty : 'id',

fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'int'
}, {
    name : 'weight',
    type : 'float'
}, {
    name : 'category_id',
    type : 'int'
}, {
    name : 'scorecard_id',
    type : 'int'
} ],
associations : [ {
    type : 'belongsTo',
    model : ModelNames.Category,
    primaryKey : 'id',
    forgientKey : 'category_id'
}, {
    type : 'belongsTo',
    model : ModelNames.ScoreCard,
    primaryKey : 'id',
    forgientKey : 'scorecard_id'
} ]});

Ext.define(ModelNames.ScoreCard, {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty : 'id',

fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'int'
}, {
    name : 'description',
    type : 'string',
    defaults : ''
}, {
    name : 'isTemplate',
    type : 'boolean',
    defaults : true
}, {
    name : 'isValid',
    type : 'boolean',
    defaults : false
} ],
associations : [ {
    type : 'hasMany',
    model : ModelNames.ScoreRecord,
    name : 'scoreRecords',
    storeConfig : {
        autoLoad : true,
        autoSync : true,
        proxy : {
            type : 'rest',
            url : '/' + CONTEXT_PATH + '/RESTFul/ScoreRecord',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'items'
            },
            writer : 'json'
        }
    }
}, {
    type : 'hasMany',
    model : ModelNames.CategoryWeight,
    name : 'categoryWeights',
    storeConfig : {
        autoLoad : true,
        autoSync : false,
        proxy : {
            type : 'rest',
            url : '/' + CONTEXT_PATH + '/RESTFul/CategoryWeight',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'items'
            },
            writer : 'json'
        }
    }
} ]});
```

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting an answer by using a question in your title.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: foreignKey

Since answers are not allowed to be less than two words, I'll add that apart from spotting the typo, I have no idea if your code will work, why or why not.

Comment: What I pointed out was his answer: he mis-typed "foreignKey". I thought calling it a typo summed it up nicely in two words. Being required by the system to enter more than two words,  added that I did not know what else might be wrong. One would certainly want to fix the obvious and try again. This additional sentence required ny the system has been used by the system to put me into comment prison. What is really so bad? I had no ill intent and it is a valid answer.

Comment: I would like to correct the typos in that comment but this system is rather fussy about it,. Seems I thought about it for more than five minutes. If there is a next time, I will compose offline.